# Protecting firmware .bin from reverse engineering

Tags: encryption, reverse-engineering, protection

I would like to protect my .bin ( squash fs ) file after compiling process in order to avoid reverse engineering techniques ( i.e. binwalk could simply unsquash my .bin firmware and see all the file system )

Could you recommend any tools for crypting the .bin file or other techniques?

Hope my question is clear

Thanks

Comment: Publishing the source code protects from reverse engineering by making it pointless. :)

Comment: Why not just design your firmware to be secure? It will not matter who reads it.

Comment: The only winning move is not to play. Look up the failure modes of the Xbox 360 and the Xbox One.

Comment: It's easier to let folks read but resist modification than it is to be unreadable _by someone who, by definition, has posession of the hardware that itself must be able to read and decrypt the content_. There absolutely are ways to make the life of a RE harder, and there also absolutely are ways to circumvent those; I've seen some very fun power-glitching attacks to get around mechanisms intended to make functionality inaccessible after early boot, f/e. So you need to think about what your threat model is, and what your engineering effort budget is.

Comment: ...but really, what _is_ the threat model? Are you worried about people who can just desolder your flash chips, for example? Are you locked into specific hardware (that may or may not have TPM support or local equivalents?) Can you afford a higher per-unit price for the sake of being able to seal keys to only be accessible with hash-append-only registers in a specific state? Do you need to worry about an attacker with a logic analyzer who's probed the traces on your board?

Comment: Anyhow -- if you build your system *thinking* that nobody can read your firmware, that leads you down the road of doing things like hardcoding passwords/secrets in the firmware. It's better to assume that attackers will be able to read the firmware and design it to still be secure _even if that happens_. Yes, add countermeasures when it's easy/cheap/low-risk/makes sense to do so; but don't build your system in such a way that if those countermeasures break your customers are screwed.

Comment: Hence, you are better off spending your time and money on code reviews, security audits, and fixing vulnerabilities in the design - instead of obfuscating your output binary.

Comment: Hey, DDBE, the usual reminder: You've got multiple highly upvoted answers and didn't accept one. Is everything alright?

Answer (score 27):

[@Marcus](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/235056/88532) is completely correct about using encryption, and how the key has to be stored somewhere safe and possibly used in conjunction with secure boot. As far as tools go, there are many symmetric and asymmetric encryption schemes that may be suitable for your use case.

However, you can't protect 100% from someone obtaining your firmware. You can only increase the difficulty of reverse engineering such that the effort required outweighs the potential reward of obtaining it. Of course, this will depend on the type of adversary; a casual user may give up immediately after seeing that it is encrypted, but a professional outfit may spend much more time and money until access is gained.

So, you can tailor your defenses to what level of threat you anticipate and balance that with what you are able/willing to spend. If you only want to protect against a casual user, it *may* be sufficient to only encrypt the firmware in transit, and have the firmware decrypted upon receipt using a key stored in firmware. This method requires very little investment on your part, but it also may fall over pretty quickly for someone who is more determined.

Of course, you can step up to using secure boot with a hardware security module, using the keys to decrypt firmware only on boot, but as mentioned, this is an architectural decision and will possibly incur more time/cost.

The problem is, even if you store the firmware encrypted in the best way possible and make the keys extremely hard to recover from the hardware, you also have to do **everything** else right. All it takes is one vulnerability in your software for a user to get a shell on your system, from where they could dump the firmware. Or, maybe there are debug ports (JTAG/SWD/UART) left on the board itself that could allow access with a little hardware hacking.

The point is, once your system is physically in someone else's hands, it's a losing battle from there. So maybe it's time to ask; what is it that you are really worried about being reverse engineered? If it's for security purposes, consider searching for and fixing vulnerabilities internally instead of hoping to hide them with security through obscurity. If you are trying to protect proprietary code, you could protect it through legal means instead of hoping nobody recovers it.

Comment: +1.  "Code security" is an *extremely* black-and-white topic in the age of the Web: if one person anywhere in the world manages to reverse-engineer your system and posts a crack online, it's cracked for everybody, forever.  So your security is either perfect or it's worthless... and it's *never* perfect.  The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: @MasonWheeler The only wining move is not to write software? That's not practical. Perhaps, by publishing the source code and encouraging an active community around it, you can convince folks to notify you of bugs before other folks exploit them.

Comment: @jpaugh No, the only winning move is to not even try to protect software you distribute into the hands of third parties from cracks.  It's a fools errand and always has been.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I wholeheartedly disagree. You're also using a very black&white picture of reality: The reality is that people will sell counterfeits of mass products. These people usually don't have the greatest engineers (their's higher-margin jobs for great engineers than cloning a bluetooth headphone). Not being the manufacturer that has the easiest to read firmware is a boon. You don't realize how low a bar can hang and still make a lot of commercial difference.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So you pick the low-hanging fruit - disable your JTAG ports, and so on.  You don't make it trivially easy.  But when it gets to someone spending serious time with a memory analyser or anything like that, you have to accept that you're going to lose that battle.  As MasonWheeler says, the answer then is not to play, because you're just falling into a money pit.  Put the same money into designing new features, and the reverse-engineers will always be on the back foot because you're constantly upgrading your firmware.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I explicitly said this is an extremely black-and-white issue because the nature of the world-wide web means that cracked once anywhere is cracked everywhere forever.  There are a lot of places where black-and-white thinking doesn't apply, but in this particular case, it absolutely does.

Comment: @MasonWheeler, ...that said, how tempting of a target a given device is matters. Not everything is sold into consumer markets. That's good and bad -- you might have fewer people interested in taking a shot at breaking the firmware, but they might be significantly better-funded or more nefarious in their intent.

Comment: (Certainly, a sufficiently resourced and motivated attacker will eventually get into _anything_, but doing one's job well enough can make a different part of a target's infrastructure be the easiest way in, rather than the device one is responsible for engineering; even if it leads to a supply-chain attack rather than a pure software one, it looks better for an engineering organization's reputation if something had to be physically tampered with to compromise a customer).

Comment: @MarcusMüller: "These people usually don't have the greatest engineers" – In the world of ubiquitous information, they don't need to. The XBox was cracked not by counterfeiters or warez groups but by students wanting to run Linux. DRM schemes were cracked not by pirates but by students wanting to watch their legally acquired movies on Linux. Licensing schemes were cracked not by warez groups but by legitimate users getting fed up with the licensing software crashing their PC.

Comment: I find it interesting that you assume Warez groups have better personell than motivated groups of students / Linux users.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I am not assuming that. Microsoft was assuming that and they got burnt by it. They defended against organized copyright pirates, but were beaten by hobbyists. For the original XBox, specifically, they assumed that copyright pirates couldn't afford the high speed oscilloscope required to sniff the secret key off the bus, but instead the key was recovered by a student who didn't *need* to afford such an oscilloscope because the EE department at his university had invented and built one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag again, very few people actually deal with consumer mass product that have so much of a community that'd be interested in breaking their product's security. Thread modeling models basically any device with a lower need for security than a gaming console. And thinking a motivated student is worse at this than some half-educated engineer at a Chinese clone shop is really not founded in reality, as you've noticed.

Answer (score 18):

What you want is impossible; there's no "tool" that can do that.

When you encrypt your file, and then only someone in ownership of the key can get the contents – that's the point of encryption. Since you still want to use it, you, however, need to supply that key to the device that will use your image. Can't include the key anywhere unencryptedly in a file, otherwise *everyone* will trivially be able to decrypt your image.

The only way encrypted images work is with hardware support for securely hardware-stored keys from the boot away. That's not a "tool", that's an architectural choice with quite big consequences for your overall boot process.

You'll probably want to look into what "Secureboot" is.

Comment: You can do that if your target platform has unique hardware keys, for example like iPhones did or some baseband controller blobs do. But it requires key management, additional enrollment/specialization and hardware trust anchors. And of course additional development and validation costs, not to mention the processing resources. Speaking of iPhones, Secure Enclave Firmware decryption keys have been published before.

Answer (score 6):

In order to prevent reverse-engineering of their [Management Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Management_Engine), Intel used:

- An obscure CPU architecture (not their own)
- an exotic compression algorithm with hardware-backed dictionary
- a less-known OS framework

Ultimately, they failed (well, almost). But they kept secret the internals of the ME for ~10 years.

Comment: I don't know if you want to call Minix lesser known :)

Comment: It became Minix later (and this, exactly this, made Minix "the most installed OS", it was rather niche product beforehand). Up to v10 (? not sure) it was ThreadX (as per wiki).